# how to Copy an item from jlist to another?

Tags: java, swing

I have a problem with copying items from one jlist to another, I set a button action listener code, it works but not as i want.  When I select an item and I press the button,
a copy of the selected item will be in jlist2

But the problem is  if I select the same item and click the button the item will be shown twice and this is no expected.

This is the code, please help as soon as possible.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 

{ 
  int[] selectedIx = jList1.getSelectedIndices();

  DefaultListModel lm = new DefaultListModel();
  ListModel list = jList2.getModel();

  for (int i = 0; i < list.getSize(); i++) {
      Object prev = list.getElementAt(i);
      lm.addElement(prev);
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < selectedIx.length; i++) {
      Object sel = jList1.getModel().getElementAt(selectedIx[i]);
      lm.addElement(sel);
  }

  jList2.setModel(lm);

}
```

thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

you are adding the elements twice into the DefaultListModel that is the reason.

```
Object prev  and Object sel
```

Comment: i have tried to use several ways .. but i stuck and i could not complete

Answer (score 1):

do like this

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)     
{ 
    List<String> selectedValuesList = jList1.getSelectedValuesList();
    jList2.setListData(selectedValuesList.toArray(new String[selectedValuesList.size()]));    
}
```

Comment: I try to do this ,,, but it does not work ..error appears ask to Add import for java.swing.list .. when i import it it says that 
"java.swing.list Does not take parameters "
i give up... @.@

Comment: @ASN please remove the java.swing.list and import this one java.util.List

Comment: ,, Sorry for disturbing you .. actually i have add  (import javax.swing.JList; ) ; however still it doesnt work .. even when i remove it and import (java.util.List ) ... it shows error in the first line at getSelectedValuesList();   Thanks for your Corporation ..

Comment: @ASN `getSelectedValuesList()` was added to java 7, so if you are compiling using an older version, the corresponding method is `getSelectedValues()`. Note the different return type, array instead of a list, so modifications are needed. (The presented solution won't keep the previously copied values though, so according to my understanding will not be what you want).

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your intent correctly, you want to copy items to `jList2` when the button is pressed, *and* avoid duplicates, *and* keep the items that have been copied earlier. Assuming `jList2` uses `DefaultListModel`, you can check if it already contains an item:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
    DefaultListModel list = (DefaultListModel) jList2.getModel();

    for (Object sel : jList1.getSelectedValues()) {
        if (list.indexOf(sel) == -1) {
            list.addElement(sel);
        }
    }
}
```

(Using recent enough java, you should also use generics and `getSelectedValuesList()`).

Comment: you understand the concept correctly ..but Do I have to replace the second for loop with the one you wrote ???????

Comment: @ASN I wrote what I intend as the complete implementation of `jButton1ActionPerformed()` (Removed both of the previous loops, reuse the existing model, etc). Note that I haven't tried it, so it is possible that some bug slipped in.