# Using an event to do something in another class in Java

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, jbutton, event-listener

based on my understanding,

```
`list_1.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
  public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent evt) {

 }}
```

will do something when something in the list was selected, and

`button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {`

do something when the button have been pushed.

I want to write a code to delete the selected item from one list and add it to another one.
I can't use Jlist methods because it is not in the scope of button. 
I am not sure how to do it. and I can't find something that solve my problem on net or books.

Thank you so much

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JList;

import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JSplitPane;

import java.awt.Component;

import javax.swing.Box;

import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JSeparator;

import java.awt.Panel;
import java.awt.List;

import javax.swing.JToolBar;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;

public class Window {

private JFrame frame;


public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Window window = new Window();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application. This is the constructor for this Window class.
 * All of the code here will be executed as soon as a Window object is made.
 */
public Window() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame. This is where Window Builder
 * will generate its code.
 */
public void initialize() {
    //creates an array for the list of components 
    String pclist[]={"case","moderboard","CPU","GPU","PSU","RAM","HDD"}; 

    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 600, 600);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

    JMenu mnFile = new JMenu("File");
    menuBar.add(mnFile);

    JMenuItem mntmLoad = new JMenuItem("Load");
    mnFile.add(mntmLoad);

    JMenuItem mntmSave = new JMenuItem("Save");
    mnFile.add(mntmSave);

    JMenuItem mntmExit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
    mnFile.add(mntmExit);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JButton button = new JButton(">>");
    button.setBounds(244, 170, 82, 36);
    button.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 15));
    frame.getContentPane().add(button);

    JButton button_1 = new JButton("<<");
    button_1.setBounds(244, 219, 82, 36);
    button_1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 15));
    frame.getContentPane().add(button_1);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBounds(0, 0, 205, 493);
    panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    panel.setLayout(null);

    JList list = new JList();// implements ActionListener;
    list.setBounds(0, 0, 205, 493);
    list.setListData(pclist); //populate the Jlist

    list.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 18));
    panel.add(list);

    JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
    panel_1.setBounds(358, 0, 212, 493);
    panel_1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel_1);
    panel_1.setLayout(null);

    JList list_1 = new JList();
    list_1.setBounds(203, 0, -200, 480);
    list_1.setSelectedIndex(0);
    list_1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 18));
    panel_1.add(list_1);

    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        //list_1.addElement("hi"); 
        System.out.println("hoi");  
        }
        });



    list.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener(){
          public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent arg0) {




          }});
    list_1.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
          public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent arg0) {





                }  
          }

    );




}
```

}

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20099397/230513).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by making your `JList`s instance variables

```
public class Window {

    private JFrame frame;

    private JList list;
    private JList list_1;
```

Make sure you're initialising the instance variables and not creating new local variables...

```
//JList list = new JList();// implements ActionListener;
list = new JList();// implements ActionListener;
//...
panel.add(list);

//JList list_1 = new JList();
list_1 = new JList();
//...
panel_1.add(list_1);
```

This now means that the `JList`s are accessible from within the context of an instance of the class...

Then in your `ActionListener`s, you can simple do something like...

```
Object selected = list.getSelectedValue();
```

or...

```
int index = list.getSelectedIndex();
```

You can then use these values to modify the state of the underlying `ListModel`...if it supports those operations...

Comment: @trashgod No, I think I snuck in just before you.  I'm not 100% about how the another question is (directly) related, but it will cover the next question the OP is likely to ask...

Comment: Yes, you are right about my question, is it anyway to copy the value between 2 jlist without using for loop???

Comment: If there's only one value, you can add it to the source's `ListModel` directly.  Unless you model supports adding multiple values in a single method call, then no, you'll have to use a loop of some kind

Comment: I am really grateful for all of your help.

Comment: I have a one more quick question, how can I read from one Jlist and write it to the other one? should I read from Jlist and write to ListModel? which method should I use? I've tried this and lot of others non of them worked
........                    listmodel_1.addElement(list.getSelectedValue());

Comment: It's all done through the model.  Using a for-loop, move through all the elements in the first model and add them to the second.